# Two list view inside a ViewPager, only one is showing

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I currently have a ViewPager with three fragments as pages. The first two pages display fragments with custom list views which are built from RSS feeds using `AsyncTask`. However, when the app runs, only one list view is displayed, the other page is just blank. (Note: I'm using ViewPagerIndicator in this project).

Main activity:

```
public class ViewPagerExample extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String[] TITLETAB = new String[] { "Latest", "New", "Misc" };
private MyAdapter mAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    mIndicator.setCurrentItem(1);


}
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return ViewPagerExample.TITLETAB.length;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        switch(position) {

        case 0:
            return new CustomizedListView();


        case 1:
            return new CustomizedListViewn();


        default:
            return null;

        }


    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return ViewPagerExample.TITLETAB[position % ViewPagerExample.TITLETAB.length].toUpperCase();
    }


     @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
             ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
        }
}}
```

ListView Fragment:

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Fragment {
// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://url.net/booking/music.xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new getFeed().execute();


}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{
    View thisfragment1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    return thisfragment1;
}


private class getFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document> {
    @Override
    protected Document doInBackground(Void... params) {

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        return doc;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        list=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);


        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


            }
        }); 
    }
}}
```

The second fragment is exactly same as above, only the URL for RSS feed is different. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: i don't know if this is the reason. But you must use SherlockFragmentActivity instead of FragmentActivity and SherlockFragment instead of Fragment when you are using ActionBarSherlock Library

Comment: Yes, actually I have removed the ActionBarSherlock related codes from the sample (sorry for not mentioning this). The app is working fine, except for the problem stated above. Thanks Archie. Edit: I have edited the question, removing the description about using ActionBarSherlock)

Comment: are u solve your problem ? i have a problem like u ...
please help me

my problem is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688921/page-not-update-and-not-show-second-page-inside-a-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Please add the line `list.notifyDataSetChanged();` After setting adapter in both the fragments `CustomizedListView & CustomizedListViewn`